# Country-wise Analysis of Movies

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to find the number of movies rented across each country. Display only those countries where at least one movie was rented. Arrange these countries in the alphabetical order.

DB: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html

Below is the written code

```
select e.country, count(a.rental_id) as rental_count
from rental a
left outer join customer b ON   (a.customer_id=b.customer_id)
left outer join address c ON    (b.address_id=c.address_id)
left outer join city d ON       (c.city_id=d.city_id)
left outer join country e ON    (d.country_id=e.country_id)
group by country 
order by rental_count >=1
```

my output is displayed as below

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Angola
4
*************************** 2. row ***************************
American Samoa
4
*************************** 3. row ***************************
Afghanistan
4
*************************** 4. row ***************************
Algeria

2
*************************** 5. row ***************************
New Zealand
1
```

How do i convert the output to Alphabetical Order

Comment: can you explain how the result should be?

Comment: The Result should be in Alphabetical Order

Comment: At this point, 20 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial on relational databases will prove beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably confusing `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`.

> Display only those countries where at least one movie was rented.

And this is how you try to do it:

```
order by rental_count >=1
```

But to filter on aggregated columns you should use the HAVING clause:

```
having rental_count >=1
```

However - You can achieve the same by using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Then no HAVING clause is needed in this case.

The ORDER BY clause is used to get the result in a specific order. If you want the countries to be sorted alphabetically, you would use

```
order by e.country
```

Comment: Thank You it worked after changing it to Inner Join and order by

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing you want to sort the results by country name acc_account_transactions  and not by count

```
order by e.country
```

Comment: I want these countries names to be displayed in Alphabetical Order

Comment: change the order by like i wrote and you will get ithe right oirde rwhen you run your query

Comment: Thank You it worked after changing it to Inner Join and order by

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.country, count(a.rental_id) as rental_count
from rental a
left outer join customer b ON   (a.customer_id=b.customer_id)
left outer join address c ON    (b.address_id=c.address_id)
left outer join city d ON       (c.city_id=d.city_id)
left outer join country e ON    (d.country_id=e.country_id)
group by country 
having rental_count >=1 order by e.country
```

The ORDER BY clause is used to get the result in a specific order. If you want the countries to be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Select Country ,count(rental_id)  as Rental_count from Country
inner join city using (country_id)
inner join address using (city_id)
inner join customer using (address_id)
inner join rental using (customer_id)
group by country
having count(rental_id) >= 1
order by Country asc;

Hi Everyone, We can get same answer by applying having clause with value >=1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
use upgrad;

select Country, count(rental_id) as Rental_count
from rental
inner join customer
using (customer_id)
inner join address
using (address_id)
inner join city
using (city_id)
inner join country
using (country_id)
group by country
order by country;
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score -1):

```
select country,count(rental_id) from country
inner join city using (country_id)
inner join address using (city_id)
inner join customer using (address_id)
inner join rental using (customer_id)
group by country
having count(rental_id)>0
order by country asc;
```

Comment: Please, add an explaination.

Answer (score -2):

```
select country, count(rental_id>=1) as rental_count
from rental
join customer using (customer_id)
join address using (address_id)
join city using (city_id)
join country using (country_id)
group by country
order by country desc;
```

Comment: Please explain what you code does. Code without explanation is useless for future readers.

Comment: query to find the number of movies rented across each country. Display only those countries where at least one movie was rented. Arrange these countries in alphabetical order.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Please [edit] your answer with your explanation, rather than adding it as a comment.